# Count Elements with Position Value, Multiply Number of Matched Elements

Tags: jquery, size, position, each

I am having some trouble figuring out how to get the number of elements that match a value. Here is my rough code:

```
var $numElements = $('#casestudy-content article').length;
console.log($numElements);
$('#casestudy-content article').each(function() {
    var $leftElements = $(this).position().left;
    if ( $leftElements === 0 ) {
        console.log($leftElements);
    }
});
```

So I can count how many elements there are in total. I can find the elements that have a position left of 0... but I do not know how to count those elements that return 0. I need to find how many elements = left: 0; and multiply that by a number. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` method.

```
var len = $('#casestudy-content article').filter(function() {
               return $(this).position().left === 0
          }).length
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to only return 0 :(

Comment: Looks like I needed a ; at the end of length. Added that, and all works! Awesome dude, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var leftAlignedElements = 0;
$('#casestudy-content article').each(function(){
   if($(this).position().left === 0){
      leftAlignedElements++;
   }
});

console.log(leftAlignedElements);
```

Comment: once you find an answer that works for you make sure to mark it as accepted. Actually "undefined"'s answer is probably better and more concise.